# How to apply background images as thumbnails in bxslider pager?

Tags: jquery, css, bxslider

I am using bxslider, thumbnails as pager. The functionality works well, but I can't seem to apply background images to the thumbnails. Anyone knows why? HTML and CSS are below.

```
<div class="thumbs">
  <a href=""></a>
  <a href=""></a>
  <a href=""></a>
  <a href=""></a>
</div>   

  .thumbs a {
    display:block;
    width:150px;
    height:100px;

    float:left;
    background-image:url('images/m2g_logo.png');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build the pager as per the instructions on [their website](http://bxslider.com/examples/thumbnails-pager-method-2).
If you want specific images for the thumbs then use the code they've specified on that page:

```
$(function(){
      $('#slider1').bxSlider({
        pager: true,
        buildPager: function(slideIndex){
          switch (slideIndex){
            case 0:
              return '<a href=""><img src="" /></a>';
            case 1:
              return '<a href=""><img src="" /></a>';
            case 2:
              return '<a href=""><img src="" /></a>';
            case 3:
              return '<a href=""><img src="" /></a>';
          }
        }
      });
    });
```

If you just want a selected/unselected image then use:

```
$(function(){
      $('#slider1').bxSlider({
        pager: true,
        buildPager: function(slideIndex){            
              return '<a href=""><div></div></a>';
        }
      });
    });
```

and set the background image styles of the child divs as per below:

```
a.pager-active > div{
    background: url("pager_selected.png") no-repeat scroll !important;
    display:inline;
    outline:none;
}

.bx-pager a > div{      
    display:inline;
    padding:2px; /*set this to half the width of your image*/
    background: url("pager_unselected.png") no-repeat scroll;
    position:relative;
    top:10px;
    outline:none;
}

.bx-pager{
    text-align:center;
 }
```